# Generate Code In a Queue

Tags: vb.net

have a Application In Vb.Net .I am Developing This Application on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 , VB.NET, Sql Server 2005 , Crystal Report.

And That Application Have Registration Form . Now My Question Is
This Application is Installed On 5 different Computer In a Network . At the Mean time all 5 users
are Open Registration form Then They click on Save button on same time . I Have a table registration , and that has a column (code) that is primary key. whenever they want to save the record only one user can get save the record . all 4 users are rollback the transaction because of primary key violation error. Therefor i want to generate code on a queue basis .. where user can wait to get a Unique Code of that Record and i dont want to users request to rollback ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to have the server generate the unique code and then deliver the registration form.

You can implement it in a way that whenever a client click on registration form, the server generates a key, probably a timestamp of the request and then pass it to the client where you can generate the form. Now, since each request will be processed by the server in a queue fashion, the timestamp generated will be different and hence a unique primary key.

Comment: Can u Explain it More I have a sql server where a registration table is created and all users are accessed that table . and my table has a unique column (Code) That is a primary key

Comment: what is timestamp and what can it do ?

Comment: can u give some example on queue

Comment: Timestamp is the date and time at which an event occurs or occurred, usually indicated in human-readable form, especially when used in a log to track events